# GraphQL: How to handle a schema with a mix of String and JSON without using graphql-type-json?

Tags: node.js, json, typescript, rest, graphql

I am new to GraphQL and still learning.
I have a rest API returning response as below:

```
    {
    "campaign_types": [
        {
            "name": "USA",
            "scenarios": [
                {
                    "id": "jsdx-sdsd-xsds",
                    "name": "NBA"
                },
                {
                    "id": "jsds-sdfs-xdfd",
                    "name": "NFL"
                }
            ],
            "id:": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "Australia",
            "scenarios": [
                {
                    "id": "jtds-sada-xdfs",
                    "name": "AFL"
                },
                {
                    "id": "klhj-sdfs-fdfs",
                    "name": "NRL"
                }
            ],
            "id:": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to convert this into a GraphQL API in another application build with `TypeScript` and `React` frontend because it handles only GraphQL API.
My requirement is in my 2nd application when I make a GraphQL API call it should return the same API response as the rest API.

I am getting this error when I have defined my GraphQL schema as below:

```
type CommsCampaignType {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    scenarios: [JSON]
}
```

Error:

```
Error: Type "JSON" not found in document
```

I saw some posts which said of using `grahql-type-json` but I would like to do it without using that if there is a way.
The end result I am looking for is in my UI I have a dropdown which shows Campaign_Type name as "USA", "Australia" and when I select that should show the respective scenario name "NBA", "NFL", and "AFL", "NRL" respectively in a 2nd dropdown. So my GraphQL API query should be able to produce that result.

If anyone could suggest a best method for this, that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `Scenario` type:

```
type Scenario {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}
```

Then use it in your `CommsCampaignType`:

```
type CommsCampaignType {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    scenarios: [Scenario]
}
```

Comment: Thank you @michelfloyd. I played around with this yesterday after posting the question and came up with the same.